# Should this phenolic hydroxyl be rotatable?

Tags: molecular-modeling, crystallography, rdkit, pikachu

Looking at [nelfinavir](https://www.rcsb.org/ligand/1UN), I get variable results from different compchem packages on whether the phenol hydroxyl oxygen should be rotatable (SP3) or non-rotatable (SP2). Which one is it?

[image: pic]

Feasibly, there are resonance forms where double bonds hop over to the oxygen from the benzene. The [crystal structures](https://www.rcsb.org/search?request=%7B%22query%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22group%22%2C%22nodes%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22group%22%2C%22nodes%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22group%22%2C%22logical_operator%22%3A%22and%22%2C%22nodes%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22terminal%22%2C%22service%22%3A%22text%22%2C%22parameters%22%3A%7B%22attribute%22%3A%22rcsb_nonpolymer_instance_feature_summary.comp_id%22%2C%22operator%22%3A%22exact_match%22%2C%22value%22%3A%221UN%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22terminal%22%2C%22service%22%3A%22text%22%2C%22parameters%22%3A%7B%22attribute%22%3A%22rcsb_nonpolymer_instance_feature_summary.type%22%2C%22operator%22%3A%22exact_match%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22HAS_COVALENT_LINKAGE%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22terminal%22%2C%22service%22%3A%22text%22%2C%22parameters%22%3A%7B%22attribute%22%3A%22rcsb_nonpolymer_instance_feature_summary.count%22%2C%22value%22%3A0%2C%22operator%22%3A%22equals%22%7D%7D%5D%7D%5D%2C%22logical_operator%22%3A%22and%22%2C%22label%22%3A%22text%22%7D%5D%2C%22logical_operator%22%3A%22and%22%7D%2C%22return_type%22%3A%22entry%22%2C%22request_options%22%3A%7B%22paginate%22%3A%7B%22start%22%3A0%2C%22rows%22%3A25%7D%2C%22results_content_type%22%3A%5B%22experimental%22%5D%2C%22sort%22%3A%5B%7B%22sort_by%22%3A%22score%22%2C%22direction%22%3A%22desc%22%7D%5D%2C%22scoring_strategy%22%3A%22combined%22%7D%2C%22request_info%22%3A%7B%22query_id%22%3A%221de521366fa394c9988d39e00dd86123%22%7D%7D) are all pretty consistent, showing a hydrogen bond from the hydroxyl that keeps the hydrogen planar with the benzene ring (consistent with SP2).

RDKit claims this oxygen is SP2:

```py
import rdkit
print(rdkit.__version__)
from rdkit import Chem
mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles('Cc1c(cccc1O)C(=O)N[C@@H](CSc2ccccc2)[C@@H](C[N@@]3C[C@H]4CCCC[C@H]4C[C@H]3C(=O)NC(C)(C)C)O')
atom = mol.GetAtomWithIdx(7)
print(atom.GetAtomicNum(), atom.GetHybridization())
```

out: `2022.09.1 \n 8 SP2`

However, some packages claim SP3. Here's one example (not picking on PIKAChU here):

```py
from pikachu.general import read_smiles
s = read_smiles('Cc1c(cccc1O)C(=O)N[C@@H](CSc2ccccc2)[C@@H](C[N@@]3C[C@H]4CCCC[C@H]4C[C@H]3C(=O)NC(C)(C)C)O')
pika_at = s.atoms[7]
print(pika_at.hybridisation)
```

out: `sp3`

Similarly, some paid packages optimize the coordinates of the bound molecule in the crystal structures, and treat the hydroxyl as rotatable. As a result of the optimization, the H-bond is no longer in-plane with the benzene, which would indicate SP3.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not an expert on these two libraries. The only question that jumps into my mind is: are you sure you're referring to the same atom among the two libraries? Do the two libraries start counting the atoms' indexes by 0?

Answer (score 5):

The experimental findings (and from higher theory levels) are:

The phenolic OH group is in plane with the aromatic ring (best lone pair overlap), with the barrier for rotation around 3.5 kcal/mol. The situation is similar in 2,6-dimethylphenol. In your case, the system is less symmetric so that you can have a preference for one position of the O-H group.

Regarding the empirical assignment, SP2 is definitely wrong. The O-H is in plane of aromatic ring for different reasons, than SP2 hybridization.

Comment: this is great, thank you! Could you fill in a few gaps please? What expmt findings are you referring to (to support the 3.5 kcal/mol barrier)? How does 'best lone pair overlap' explain this barrier - is it avoiding overlap or maximising overlap, and between what atoms?

Comment: to play devil's advocate here, WolframAlpha says 'sp2' (as does my old first year textbook): https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=orbital+hybridization+in+phenol+and+cyclohexanol

Comment: -OH has a withdrawing group in its meta position so the pull is not as strong compared to ortho and para.  A complete charge-transferred `sp2` is a correct but less abundant resonance form. Look at the carbon and proton NMRs of nelfinavir in the SI here: https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.joc.8b00039

Comment: @leviso1 The barrier for C-O rotation can be determined by different methods, one quite accurate and esoteric is rotational spectroscopy, see https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-2860(69)85029-5
The lone pairs of oxygen should overlap with the pi-system of the aromatic ring. This is best achieved when the oxygen is sp3, then both pairs are ~19 degrees from perpendicular to the benzene plane.
Would you use sp2 O, one lone pair is perpendicular to benzene plane, but the second is in plane, therefore no resonance.